# Redux does not change values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

my Redux does not change the variables value. I am trying to test out Redux but I really cant find what I am doing wrong. For now I am only trying to Log a value but the value does not change.

This is my ReduxActions:

```
export const TEST_FUNC = 'TEST_FUNC';

export const testFunc = () => {
    
    const theTestingString = "TAG testing redux";

    return {
        type: TEST_FUNC,
        payload: theTestingString
    }
}
```

In my Reducer I give the variable a initial value, and in my Actions file I am trying to change that value but when I console.log(testRedux) I only get the initial value. here is my Reducer:

```
import { TEST_FUNC } from "../actions/firebaseActions";

const initialState = {
    theTestingString: 'Initial Value',
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {

        switch(action.type) {
            case TEST_FUNC: 
            console.log("HSKJDKJSKFDBSKJKAJDL")
            return {
                ...state,
                theTestingString: action.payload
            }
        }

        return state;
}
```

Here is my Store:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import firebaseReducer from './reducers/firebaseReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    firebaseTest: firebaseReducer
});

const middleware = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default createStore(rootReducer, middleware);
```

Here is where I am trying to log the value:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {Button, Card, TextInput} from 'react-native-paper';
import { FirebaseContext } from '../../context/FirebaseContext';
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const initialUserState = {
    userName: 'Nicole Lopez',
    password: '1001008888',
}

export default function LoginScreen() {
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
    const [userState, setUserState] = useState(initialUserState);
    const testRedux = useSelector(state => state.firebaseTest.theTestingString);
    //const fbContext = React.useContext(FirebaseContext);
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    console.log("Logging right away: " + testRedux);

    const onInputChange = (field, value) => {
        setUserState({
            ...userState,
            [field]: value
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setDisabled(userState.userName.length === 0 || userState.password.length === 0);
    }, [userState.userName, userState.password])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
            <Card style={styles.card}>

                <TextInput
                    mode="outlined"
                    label="Förnamn & Efternman"
                    defaultValue={userState.userName}
                    onChangeText={text => onInputChange("username", text)}
                    right={<TextInput.Icon name="account" onPress={() => {
                    }}/>}
                    style={styles.textInput}/>

                <TextInput
                    mode="outlined"
                    label="Anställningsnummer 100100xxxx"
                    defaultValue={userState.password}
                    right={<TextInput.Icon name="lock"/>}
                    onChangeText={text => onInputChange("password", text)}
                    style={styles.textInput}/>
            </Card>

            <View style={styles.buttonRow}>

                <Button
                    color={disabled ? "gray" : undefined}
                    disabled={disabled}
                    mode={'contained'}
                    icon={'login'}
                    onPress={() => {
                        //console.log("The func: " + testRedux)
                        console.log("The variable: " + testRedux)
                        //console.log(fbContext)
                        //console.log("TAG isUserSignedIn: " + fbContext?.isuserSignedIn)
                        //console.log("TAG testLog:::: " + fbContext?.testLog())
                        //fbContext?.testLog()
                        //console.log("TAG LOGIN BTN PRESSED")
                        //navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
                    }}>Login</Button>
            </View>
        </View>
  );
}
```

This is my App.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {StackScreens} from './src/helpers/types';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {SafeAreaProvider} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen/HomeScreen';
import {doc, getFirestore, onSnapshot, setDoc, Unsubscribe as UnsubscribeFS} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { FirebaseContextProvider, FirebaseContext } from './src/context/FirebaseContext';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

import store from './src/redux/Store';


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Content />
    </Provider>  
  );
}

export const Content = () => {

  const navigationRef = useNavigationContainerRef();
  const firebaseContext = useContext({FirebaseContext});

  return (
    
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="LoginScreen">
          <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} /> 
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
      
  );
}
```

I am new to ReactNative, I have tried Context but I got a similar issue, maybe I'm doing something in the wrong order?

Comment: Since you are new to it: it is not an 'issue'. How a state management library/pattern in this case works is, there are 2 concepts: *consuming* the state (`useSelector`), basically read the state and be subscribed to change event for when that state is changed, and *actions*, or changing the state (`useDispatch`, see the answer below). Right now, you are just 'reading' the state, you aren't doing anything to 'change' it. This is just a brief 'explanation'.

Comment: ooh, ok so I have to first useDispatch to actually change the value of the variable and then useSelector to read the new value? Just trying to wrap my mind around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to the comments I got on my post. in my LoginScreen I added:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const testRedux = useSelector(state => state.firebaseTest.theTestingString);
```

I Added a useEffect that changes the value of the String by calling it in the useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
     dispatch(firebaseAction.testFunc());
     console.log("Entering useEffekt")
 }, [dispatch]);
```

This was how I logged it. Here I get the string in both logs:

```
console.log("The variable: ", testRedux)
console.log("The variable with a + : " + testRedux)
```

Here is the entire LoginScreen file:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {Button, Card, TextInput} from 'react-native-paper';
import { FirebaseContext } from '../../context/FirebaseContext';
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import * as firebaseAction from '../../redux/actions/firebaseActions';


const initialUserState = {
    userName: 'Nicole Lopez',
    password: '1001008888',
}

export default function LoginScreen() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const testRedux = useSelector(state => state.firebaseTest.theTestingString);

    //const testRedux = useSelector(state => state.firebaseTest.theTestingString);

    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
    const [userState, setUserState] = useState(initialUserState);
    //const testRedux = useSelector(state => state.firebaseTest.theTestingString);
    //const fbContext = React.useContext(FirebaseContext);
    const navigation = useNavigation();


    const onInputChange = (field, value) => {
        setUserState({
            ...userState,
            [field]: value
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(firebaseAction.testFunc());
        console.log("Entering useEffekt")
    }, [dispatch]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setDisabled(userState.userName.length === 0 || userState.password.length === 0);
    }, [userState.userName, userState.password])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
            <Card style={styles.card}>

                <TextInput
                    mode="outlined"
                    label="Förnamn & Efternman"
                    defaultValue={userState.userName}
                    onChangeText={text => onInputChange("username", text)}
                    right={<TextInput.Icon name="account" onPress={() => {
                    }}/>}
                    style={styles.textInput}/>

                <TextInput
                    mode="outlined"
                    label="Anställningsnummer 100100xxxx"
                    defaultValue={userState.password}
                    right={<TextInput.Icon name="lock"/>}
                    onChangeText={text => onInputChange("password", text)}
                    style={styles.textInput}/>
            </Card>

            <View style={styles.buttonRow}>

                <Button
                    color={disabled ? "gray" : undefined}
                    disabled={disabled}
                    mode={'contained'}
                    icon={'login'}
                    onPress={() => {

                        console.log("The variable: ", testRedux)
                        console.log("The variable with a + : " + testRedux)
                        //console.log(fbContext)
                        //console.log("TAG isUserSignedIn: " + fbContext?.isuserSignedIn)
                        //console.log("TAG testLog:::: " + fbContext?.testLog())
                        //fbContext?.testLog()
                        //console.log("TAG LOGIN BTN PRESSED")
                        //navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
                    }}>Login</Button>
            </View>
        </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to dispatch an action to run the reducer.

Top Level:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
```

inside component:

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

When you want to change the value:

```
dispatch({
  type: TEST_FUNC,
  payload: "TAG testing redux" (or whatever value you want to add to the reducer)
});
```

Right now i only see the useSelector pulling data from redux, which only gives you the initial state because you havnt dispatched any new values to redux.

Comment: I tried this and when I try to log the value now I get this in my console log: The variable: [object Object]

Comment: @NicoleLopez That is simply how js works. Instead of `console.log("Logging right away: " + testRedux);`, do `console.log("Logging right away: ", testRedux);` (you have it in 2 places)

Comment: This works, I read the comment above and changed my dispatch as you told me, thank you! I changed my log and the log I got is: {type: 'TEST_FUNC', payload: 'TAG testing redux'} this may sound like a not so smart question but why don't I get the only the string value? why do I get it like so?

Comment: what happens when you only select `state => state`

Comment: I get a undefined variable

Comment: I got it now, It was a combination of your anser and go @ergis comment.